# Given math model to model relations using a tensor, how do we put restriciton on tensor so that it can capture symmetric relations

Tags: multilinear-algebra

The goal is to model real life relations between stuff and people.
Say we have sets $E$, $R$ and functions $h:E \to V$, $t :E \to W$ and $r:R \to U$, where $V,W,U$ are finite dimentional vector spaces with potentially distinct dimentions but all with the same underlying field.

The idea is that $E$ is the set of stuff and people, $R$ is the possible kind of relations between them.  For example, thing is $E$ could be John Smith, table, star_wars etc. Thins in $R$ could be "is_fighting_with", "lives_in", "in_love_with" etc. The functions $h,t,r$ are just mapping that let us represent the stuff ans relations.  Here relations is a tuple in $(a,r,b)\in E\times R\times E$. So because stuff $a$ could be in the head of the tuple or the tail of the tuple, so we have two maps $h,t$ for that.

We can then tell how strong the relation r is between a and b by using a tensor product with a predefined tensor $\chi$:

$\chi\times_1 h(a)\times_2r(r) \times_3 t(b)$.
Here $\times_i$ is the mode_i product.

You see the idea? And the value of the tensor product will give the indication of stronngess of the relation between a and b.

Now some relations are symmetric. For example, "mutualy_in_love","slept_with","as_smart_as". Let's denote the relaiton by "equals_to", well in this case, we want to put restriction on $\chi$ such that $\chi\times_1 h(i)\times_2r(equals-to) \times_3 t(j)=\chi\times_1 h(j)\times_2r(equals-to) \times_3 t(i)$ for all $i,j \in \mathcal{E}$.

SO my question is: what is the restriction we put on $\chi$

Comment: We could simplify this by removing $R$ and talking about just a single relation at a time. Let's say $E$ is the set of people, and we want to talk about the "mutually in love" relation. Usually we would model this relation as a certain subset $L \subseteq E \times E$ such $(e, f) \in L$ means "$e$ is mutually in love with $f$". We expect that $L$ is _symmetric_ meaning that $(e, f) \in L \iff (f, e) \in L$. So the subset $L \subseteq E \times E$ is defining the relation...

Comment: ...equivalently, we could think of $L$ as a function $L \colon E \times E \to \{0, 1\}$, where $L(e, f) = 1$ if and only if $e$ is mutually in love with $f$. (Subsets are the same thing as functions taking the values 0 and 1). This extends more nicely to a vector space picture. Now suppose that $e, f$ etc are vectors in some vector space $V$. Define a bilinear map $L \colon V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ by $L(e, f) = 1$ iff $e$ and $f$ are mutually in love. (You might need all the people to be linearly independent for this to work). So I think the bilinear map $L$ is defining the relation here.

Comment: As for what restriction you need to put on this bilinear map, you just want the restriction that $L(v_1, v_2) = L(v_2, v_1)$, in other words $L$ is a _symmetric bilinear form_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that

> The restriction you desire is on $\chi$ is that $\chi: \text{Sym}^2(V)^* \times U \longrightarrow Z$; i.e. that $\chi$ be a function on on the symmetric bilinear functions $\text{Sym}^2(V)^* \times U$.

**But technically the restriction you desire is on $r$ and not on $\chi$**. The idea is the following:

> $r$ (or $R$) is itself a tensor, in particular, it is a bilinear
>   tensor and $\chi$ is a trilinear tensor. *The relations being symmetric forces the tensor $r$ to be symmetric,* $\chi$ only "implicitly inherits its symmetry from $r$."

**Intuitive Explanation**

If $R$ is the set of relations then $R \subset \mathcal{P}(E \times E)$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is the powerset operator (if $R$ were just *one relation we would have $R \subset E \times E$*); therefore it makes sense to think of $R$ as having "one more extra dimension than a regular relation." A relation is nothing more than a boolean (i.e. $0-1$) matrix; our set of relations is nothing more than a boolean (i.e. $0-1$) "3-D array." In other words if $r' \in R$ and $e,e' \in E $ and $er'e'$ is true then the most reasonable value to give to (the coordinate) $r(r')_{e,e'}$ is one, likewise if $er'e'$ is false then $r(r')_{e,e'}=0$. If all of the $r' \in R$ are symmetric then $r(r')_{e,e'} = r(r')_{e',e}$ and therefore $\chi $ can defined as any (3-linear) function on "symmetric 3-D arrays" with the dimensions of $r$. *Therefore [symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor) is a restriction on the 3-D array $r$ and not on $\chi$; as a matter of fact we will eventually dispense with the superfluous function/tensor $\chi$ altogether.*

**Rigorous Explanation**

Let's make this definition more rigorous:

1. enumerate each $e \in E$ by a number in $\{1,...,|E|\}$,
2. likewise enumerate each $r' \in R$ by a number in $\{1,...,|R|\}$,
3. let $v_i$ be a basis for $V$ and $u_i$ be a basis for $U$, where $\dim (V) = |E|$ and $\dim (U) = |R|$
4. and let $h: E \rightarrow  V$ send the element $e_i$ to $v_i$

then we define the bilinear function $r : V \times V \rightarrow U$ (i.e. "3-D" matrix/array) as 
\begin{equation}
r(v_{i} , v_j  ) = \sum_{k}r_{i,j}^ku_k
\end{equation}
where the coefficients are defined by 
\begin{equation}
r_{i,j}^k = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } e_i r_k' e_ j \text{ is true}\\
0 & \text{if } e_i r_k' e_ j \text{ is false}  
\end{cases};
\end{equation}
this is well defined by linearity since a (multi-)linear mapping is uniquely defined by its behavior on a basis, in this case the basis is $b_i \otimes b_j \in V\bigotimes V$, see the [universal mapping property for a "category theory" explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_(intrinsic_definition)#Universal_property). Technically you also need to know the [universal property for direct sums of vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules#Universal_property). Intuitively $V$ is the direct sum of the lines $L_i = \{c v_i \ | \ c \in \mathbb{F} \}$ i.e. $V = \bigoplus_i L_i$; and $V \otimes V$ is the space defined by the direct sum of the planes $L_i \bigotimes L_j  = \{ c (e_i \otimes e_j) \ | \ c \in \mathbb{F} \}$; i.e. $V \otimes V = \bigoplus_{i,j} L_i \bigotimes L_j$, and $r$ being a [symmetric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor) is the same as saying that $r$ does not depend on the [orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)#Multilinear_algebra) of the planes $L_i \otimes L_j$; i.e. $r$ has no "*[right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)#Geometric_algebra)*."

> **The restriction that the relations be symmetric is a restriction on the tensor $r$.** It is nothing more than the rule that $r(b_{i} , b_j  )= r(b_{j} , b_i  )$ for all $i,j$; ***i.e.* $r$ is a [symmetric bilinear tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor).** We express by saying that $r \in \text{Sym}^2(V)^* \times U$.

You are now free to define $\chi: \text{Sym}^2(V)^* \times U \longrightarrow Z$ (where $X^{*}$ is the [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) of $X$ and $Z$ is some other vector space) however you please; in particular, the succinct notation $\chi: \text{Sym}^2(V)^* \times U \longrightarrow Z$ expresses the fact that $\chi$ is a function *on* the "set of symmetric relations" $\text{Sym}^2(V)^* \times U$.

**A Generalization Beyond 0-1/true-false**

It seems the reason you want to define some extra parameter $\chi$ is that you would like to like to generalize the relations $r \in R$ to have values other than $\{0,1\}$. *This can be done directly with $r$ as well, there is no reason to introduce a superfluous $\chi$*. Let me elaborate; in the definition of $r^k_{i,j}$ we could have instead written 
\begin{equation}
r_{i,j}^k =  
\alpha \ \ \ \ \text{      if the relation } e_i r_k 'e_ j \text{  is $\alpha$ strong}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha$ is a scaler, *i.e.* $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$, that measures the strength of the relation $e_i r_k' e_ j$. Nothing else in the definition needs to be modified since $r$ was already defined to be a bilinear symetric tensor. The $\chi$ you are looking for is the $\alpha $ above.

**Computer Science Explanation**

Just in case you may be asking "But Pedro I really like the Function $\chi$ and I don't care for all of this abstraction, can you do it with the $\chi$?" the answer is **no**. The rationale is that introducing the parameter $\chi$ into "I don't know, say a machine-learning algorithm" would **increase the complexity of the algorithm by a large linear factor.** The rationale is the following: if you have a 4-D array $\chi$ that is a function of $\left(V^* \right)^{2} \times U$ (or $E^2 \times R$) then you will have **four nested for-loops**, as opposed to the **three nested for-loops for the simpler $r^k_{i,j}$.** Dropping the $\chi$ altogether has practical computational implications. As a matter of fact, we can take this further; it is a well-known fact that although the general vector space, $\left(V^{*}\right)^2$, of bilinear forms $T : V^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{F} $ has dimension $[\dim (V)]^2$ we have that the vector space, $\text{Sym}^2\left(V\right)^*$, of symmetric bilinear forms $T : V^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{F} $ has dimension $\binom{\dim (V)}{2}$, *which further cuts the number of operations by more than half.*